# I found the .bin firmware for my Simple.TV device. Binwalk comes up blank. Anything I can do?

Tags: firmware

While poking around at the headers and such from my new Simple.TV DVR, I found it downloading a file named rssflash_1035_201311211539.update00.bin. I ran binwalk to look for anything obvious, but it came up blank. I suspect it might be encrypted (?).  Any thoughts about what I could do next to get more information about this?

The download link to the file, in case anyone else is interested: 
[redacted]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the file with a hex editor (or even a text editor), you can see that the first four bytes of the file are `hsqs` (`0x68` `0x73` `0x71` `0x73`).

If you then [Google for `hsqs`](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22hsqs%22), the first link explains that it's the beginning of a [SquashFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) image.

Comment: It is odd though that binwalk doesn't report anything, as per OP.

Answer (score 2):

Use a current. up to date version of binwalk, it works fine

```
$ binwalk rssflash_1035_201311211539.update00.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: 83899310 bytes,  3291 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: Fri Nov 22 00:48:15 2013
```

Or you can use Firmware Mod Kit's `unsquash-all` to unsquash it.